# I hid the scrolling bar (but it should exist) and now I can't scroll

Tags: css

Sorry for the almost comic title, I wasn't able to explain the problem in a better way.

I thought I had finished my menu http://www.jcml.pt/2 but then I noticed that in some browsers (firefox, IE) the "hidden" scrollbar would still display and mess up my menu. In Chrome and Android everything would work as intended.

I opened a question and was later able to fix that problem by creating an extra container div and changing the code to http://www.jcml.pt/3 (adding extra container divs)

But even being hidden the scrolling should be possible but it does not work.
Edit: You might need to reduce the height of the window to see that in version2 you can scroll but in version3 you can't)

Please let me know if there's need for more details, to highlight parts of the code here or a better explanation of the issue.
When I'm less burned out from hours looking at this I can also try to create a fiddle with a simplified version of the site if need be.

**Edit:** Here's a fiddle so it's easier to see the code and where I removed part of the navigation that doesn't interfere whit this situation. http://jsfiddle.net/jcml/pyoqauLr/

Most relevant part of the code:

**CSS**

```
html, body {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.menu {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;

.m1 {
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
}

.outer-container {
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}

.inner-container {
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    width: 100%;
}

.inner-container::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}

.links {
    height: 100%;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<body>
<div class="menu m1 corner">
    <div class="outer-container">
        <div class="inner-container">
            <div class="links">
```

Comment: Please include code in the question it self, just enough to replicate the question.

Comment: I'm adding a fiddle where I removed a chunk from the html and css.